# How to Show & Hide div dynamically at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am new to HTML an JS I am trying to create a function that will only show the div that wanted to show I wanted to make it dynamic because the div can be more than 5. I wanted like the first button I only wanted to show D1 div the rest of div will be hide if I click button 2 the d1 will be hide and d3 above. I will really appreciate any advice or help thank you

```js
function myFunction(t, n) {
  var g = t + n;

  var x = document.getElementById(g);
  if (g === "D1") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    //hide div d2 to d5 or more div  only show d1
  } else if (g === "D2") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    //hide div d1 then d3 to d5 or more div  only show d2

  } else if (g === "D3") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else if (g === "D4") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else if (g === "D5") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }

}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction('D','1')">B1</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('D','2')">B2</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('D','3')">B3</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('D','4')">B4</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('D','5')">B5</button>


<div id="D1" style="Display:none">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>

<div id="D2" style="Display:none">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>
<div id="D3" style="Display:none">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>
<div id="D4" style="Display:none">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>
<div id="D5" style="Display:none">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer should be a forEach loop. I added number to the divs to make it more clear what happens:

```
    <button onclick="myFunction('D','1')">B1</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('D','2')">B2</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('D','3')">B3</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('D','4')">B4</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('D','5')">B5</button>

<div id="D1" style="Display:none">
  This is my DIV 1 element.
</div>

<div id="D2" style="Display:none">
  This is my DIV 2 element.
</div>
<div id="D3" style="Display:none">
  This is my DIV 3 element.
</div>
<div id="D4" style="Display:none">
  This is my DIV 4 element.
</div>
<div id="D5" style="Display:none">
  This is my DIV 5 element.
</div>
```

Your function now looks for all divs via a querySelectorAll and adds visibility if it matches the passed id and hides it otherwise:

```
function myFunction(t, n) {
  var g = t + n;
  // get all Divs
const allDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
  allDivs.forEach(div => {
    if(div.id == t+n) {
      div.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      div.style.display = "none"
    }
  })
}
```

You can also checkout the [pen](https://codepen.io/Gh05d/pen/jOObPWO).

Answer (score 0):

First, hide all, then show the only one you want to show.

```js
function myFunction(t, n) {

  // first hide all
  for ( var i=1; i<=5; i++ ) {
     document.getElementById(t+i).style.display = 'none';
  }

  // then show only one
  document.getElementById(t+n).style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction('D','1')">B1</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('D','2')">B2</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('D','3')">B3</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('D','4')">B4</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('D','5')">B5</button>


<div id="D1" style="Display:none">
  This is my DIV1 element.
</div>

<div id="D2" style="Display:none">
  This is my DIV2 element.
</div>
<div id="D3" style="Display:none">
  This is my DIV3 element.
</div>
<div id="D4" style="Display:none">
  This is my DIV4 element.
</div>
<div id="D5" style="Display:none">
  This is my DIV5 element.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(t, n) {
  var g = t + n;
  for(let i=1;i<=5;i++){
    //Check class is show
    let currentClassName = t+i;
    if(currentClassName  == g){
      document.getElementById(currentClassName).style.display = "block"
    }else{
      document.getElementById(currentClassName).style.display = "none"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(t) {
  ['D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D5'].forEach((div) => {
    if (div !== t) {
      document.getElementById(div).style.display = "none";
    } else {
      document.getElementById(div).style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction('D1')">B1</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('D2')">B2</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('D3')">B3</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('D4')">B4</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('D5')">B5</button>


<div id="D1" style="Display:none">
  This is my D1 DIV element.
</div>

<div id="D2" style="Display:none">
  This is my D2 DIV element.
</div>
<div id="D3" style="Display:none">
  This is my D3 DIV element.
</div>
<div id="D4" style="Display:none">
  This is my D4 DIV element.
</div>
<div id="D5" style="Display:none">
  This is my D5 DIV element.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(t, n) {
  var g = t + n;
var dates = document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="D"]');
for (var i=0;i<dates.length;i++) {
dates[i].style.display= "none";
}
  var x = document.getElementById(g);
  if (g === "D1") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    //hide div d2 to d5 or more div  only show d1
  } else if (g === "D2") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    //hide div d1 then d3 to d5 or more div  only show d2

  } else if (g === "D3") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else if (g === "D4") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else if (g === "D5") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }

}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction('D','1')">B1</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('D','2')">B2</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('D','3')">B3</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('D','4')">B4</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('D','5')">B5</button>


<div id="D1" style="Display:none">
  This is my DIV element1.
</div>

<div id="D2" style="Display:none">
  This is my DIV element2.
</div>
<div id="D3" style="Display:none">
  This is my DIV element3.
</div>
<div id="D4" style="Display:none">
  This is my DIV element4.
</div>
<div id="D5" style="Display:none">
  This is my DIV element5.
</div>
```